# Как задать изменение цвета textview в listview в зависимости от значения?

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter

Привет всем! Подскажите, пожалуйста, начинающему разработчику, как можно изменить цвет textview в listview в зависимости от значения данных в этом textview? На данный момент использую simple adapter который берет данные из json'a. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Под зависимостью от значения имею ввиду, например красный цвет если значение отрицательное, и зеленый для положительного числа.

Comment: В сторону кастомных адаптеров и книги https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141049718/.

Comment: спасибо, как раз недавно эта книга бросилась в глаза в посте на хабре)